# fieldset form with Table-like layout with CSS?

Tags: jquery

I have an application in which I'm currently using a two column table in order to get accurate cell alignment of the left column labels/descriptions with the right column form fields.

I'd like to convert it to css and use jQuery to expand/collapse specific sections.

I've seen some jQuery libraries, the menu.js in particular. And they appear to all use list items for the markup. I'm OK with converting my table to UL/LI structure if that's what I need to do.

Just looking for some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part (the styling) is handled nicely in [this A List Apart article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms/).

The second part - I don't know. Maybe a [JQuery accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion)? Or plain old `toggle` switches - that's down to what your form looks like, I would say.

Comment: jQuery accordion was the ticket. Thanks as always Pekka.